# How to make Django migrations know about changes inside a custom field?

Tags: django, django-models, models, django-migrations

I've made custom field, which is basically "upgraded" `ForeignKey` field. However, I forgot to set `on_delete=models.PROTECT` as default (desired default behaviour of that field).

```
class MyReferenceField( models.ForeignKey ):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_args = { 
            'null': True,
            'blank': True,
            'to': Photo,
            #'on_delete': models.PROTECT,  #forgotten property, that I'm adding to the field
        }
        my_args.update( kwargs )
        super(MyReferenceField, self).__init__(**my_args)

    ... MORE STUFF ...
```

Nothing changes if I add `on_delete` to `kwargs`. If I add `on_delete` to constructor call(ie. manually on each usage of field), then it works.

I want to update every usage/instance of that field, to have `on_delete` set to the `PROTECT`. So, how can I make Django know about change of default behavior/properties of a field?

Edit - clarifications: I'm using the native migrations as of Django 1.7. I've found [`deconstruct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction), but I don't know how exactly should I use it for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you are using the native migrations as of Django 1.7 or South you probably need to either add a [`deconstruct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction)-method to your custom field or a [`south_field_triple`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html).

Comment: I've found deconstruct. How can I exactly use it for that case? What do I have to do in it?